# How can I modify this SQL query to exclude all results except from the previous two hours?

Tags: sql, sql-server

We're currently using SQL Express on SQL Server 2005 and want to set up an automated ftp file transfer every two hours to our client.  We want to be able to send them bi-hourly uploads without duplicates throughout the day.  Is this possible to do by modifying this existing query?

```
    Use Sweet
    select distinct d.AccountCode, f.ProcessedFileName, f.CallStartDateTime, f.PathToFile 
    from CSR_CallDetail d, CSR_FileListing f
    where d.CallId = f.CallId 
    and f.ProcessedFileName like '%mp3'
    and f.CallStartDateTime between convert(varchar(10),getdate()-1,101) and convert(varchar(10),getdate(),101)
    and d.AccountCode > '740000'
    and f.AccountCode > '740000'
    and not exists (select 1 from( select processedfilename from csr_filelisting) p 
                                 where f.compressedfilename = p.processedfilename)
```

Here's the updated query

```
    Use Sweet
    select distinct d.AccountCode, f.ProcessedFileName, f.CallStartDateTime, f.PathToFile 
    from CSR_CallDetail d, CSR_FileListing f
    where d.CallId = f.CallId 
    and f.ProcessedFileName like '%mp3'
    and DATEDiff(hh, f.callstartdatetime, GETDATE ()) <=2
    and d.AccountCode > '740000'
    and f.AccountCode > '740000'
    and not exists (select 1 from( select processedfilename from csr_filelisting) p where f.compressedfilename = p.processedfilename)
```

Comment: What is the datatype of CallStartDateTime?

Comment: Uhh... yeah, you can modify it by replacing it with one that does what you want? Less flippantly, why does it have to be a modification of this query? Do you know SQL?

Comment: What does this query not do that you would like it to do? What have you tried and why did that not work?

Comment: data type is datetime   -   a new query is fine if it will return what is needed   -   very limited SQL knowledge  --  it will not pull files that have happened in the last 2 hours it only pulls everything from the previous day

Comment: getdate() is "now". getdate()-1 is one day ago, so that's where your "previous day" is coming from. But a more usual way to subtract dates is using datediff(), which somebody just posted below. A more important point is avoiding duplicates. A simple way to do that is to run a process which runs a minute or two after the hour, and selects only items from greater than the whole hour two hours ago, up to and including the most recent whole hour.

Comment: And please stop using the SQL antipattern of implicit joins. They are more subject to error and harder to maintain.

Comment: @HLGEM I'm unfamiliar with the idea of an implicit join.  Is this the use of "and" and "where"?

Comment: Yes and it is very poor programming technique that was replaced in the last century with something better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the query you posted returns desired result. If so, we need a date (and time) the records have been saved. All you need is to add condition:

```
AND DATEDIFF(hh, date_of_record, GETDATE()) <=2
```

I assume in your case it will be:

```
AND DATEDIFF(hh, f.CallStartDateTime , GETDATE()) <=2
```

Comment: We've updated the query using the datediff() instead of getdate() with the <=2, but we're getting results from the current hour included in this. @qbeck

Comment: We've added a getdate() >0 to prevent the current hour from appearing.  Seems like the statement does what we need it to.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Doesn't `getdate()>0` mean `getdate()>'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'`? Am I wrong? Since then it will always be true. If you want exclude current hour, I would add `f.CallStartDateTime < getdate()`. But beware of your query slip -you can miss some data.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to rely on timestamps to get guaranteed exact sequential nonoverlapping sets of anything.  You'll always be up against a race condition.  What you should do is add a `bit` column somewhere that will mean you've already processed that row, and set it appropriately at the time of processing.  Use transactions and isolation levels to ensure that no one is updating it while you're working on it (a brief moment, one hopes).